# Как сделать имя в виде ссылки aiogram 3.x

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Всех приветствую, подскажите, как сделать full_name в виде ссылки на профиль, вроде всё просто, но никак не могу понять, и не одной статьи не нашел
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Есть доп.параметр -  parse_mode='MarkdownV2'

````
**жирный**
__курсив__ `код` 
~~перечеркнутый~~ 
```блок кода```
 ||скрытый текст|| 
(ссылка)[https://smth.com]
````

Например:

```
send_message(ID, "(MyTG)[https://t.me/username]", parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await message.answer('<a href="ссылка">текст</a>', parse_mode='HTML')
```

Можно использовать разметку HTML, если указать в `parse_mode` значение `HTML`.
Также можно делать текст **жирным**: `<b>` или *курсивным*: `<i>` (даже на `stackoverflow` есть такая функция)